# Install dbt vault

Tags: dbt

dbtvault has already been added to the packages.yml file, the yaml file looks like this:

I am following a tutorial that can be found here: [dbtset_up](https://dbtvault.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worked_example/we_setup/)

This is a tutorial that I will on snowflake so that I can be able to provide the metadata and it will generate the sql for us and the required links and hubs.

```
name: dbtvault_snowflake_demo
profile: dbtvault_snowflake_demo
version: '5.3.0'
require-dbt-version: ['>=1.0.0', '<2.0.0']
config-version: 2

analysis-paths:
  - analysis
clean-targets:
  - target
seed-paths:
  - seeds
macro-paths:
  - macros
model-paths:
  - models
test-paths:
  - tests
target-path: target

vars:
  load_date: '1992-01-08'
  tpch_size: 10 #1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000

models:
  dbtvault_snowflake_demo:
    raw_stage:
      tags:
        - 'raw'
      materialized: view
    stage:
      tags:
        - 'stage'
      enabled: true
      materialized: view
    raw_vault:
      tags:
        - 'raw_vault'
    materialized: incremental
      hubs:
        tags:
          - 'hub'
  links:
    tags:
      - 'link'
  sats:
    tags:
      - 'satellite'
  t_links:
    tags:
      - 't_link'
```

I am getting an error when I ran this command:

```
dbt depsdbt
```

The error is as follows:

```
 usage: dbt [-h] [--version] [-r RECORD_TIMING_INFO] [-d] [--log-format {text,json,default}] 
    [- 
  -no-write-json]
       [--use-colors | --no-use-colors] [--printer-width PRINTER_WIDTH] [--warn-error] [--no- 
version-check]
       [--partial-parse | --no-partial-parse] [--use-experimental-parser] [--no-static-parser] 
[--profiles-dir PROFILES_DIR]
       [--no-anonymous-usage-stats] [-x] [--event-buffer-size EVENT_BUFFER_SIZE] [-q] [--no- 
 print]
       [--cache-selected-only | --no-cache-selected-only]
       
 {docs,source,init,clean,debug,deps,list,ls,build,snapshot,run,compile,parse,test,seed,run- 
operation} ...
dbt: error: argument 
{docs,source,init,clean,debug,deps,list,ls,build,snapshot,run,compile,parse,test,seed,run- 
 operation}: invalid choice: 'depsdbt' (choose from 'docs', 'source', 'init', 'clean', ' 
'debug', 'deps', 'list', 'ls', 'build', 'snapshot', 'run', 'compile', 'parse', 'test', 
'seed', 'run-operation')
```

Answer (score 1):

The command is:

```
dbt deps
```

I believe you tried to execute `dbt depsdbt`, which is not a command